# Error: Activity class {com.example.cupcake/com.example.cupcake.MainActivity} does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I uninstalled the app on the device. And then when I tried to Run the app in Android Studio, it returned this:

```
Error while executing: am start -n "com.example.cupcake/com.example.cupcake.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.cupcake/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.example.cupcake/com.example.cupcake.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

Error while Launching activity
And I've been trying to re-install the app onto the device but I can't figure out how to force Android Studio to re-install the Project back onto the device.
Android Studio Version: Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I too faced the same issue before. This is because the app is not uninstalled properly and some app data remained as it is.

**Solution:**

1. On the right side of the studio there is **Gradle** option
2. Inside **Gradle** your app name will be shown. In that, there will be 2 other options **Tasks & app**
3. Navigate to app -> Task -> Install -> uninstallAll

[image: Image for clarification]

Comment: Also on a side note, check if you have that activity listed in `AndoridManifest.xml`